# iOS17.2 UITextView click rich text( link ) crash

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUeHP.png)

crash info

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITextInteractableLinkItem attachment]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003e9fb80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a519761 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011edab904 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a52e873 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a51def4 ***forwarding*** + 1459
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a5200f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKitCore                           0x000000015bea3005 __56-[_UITextInteractableItemCache itemForAttachment:range:]_block_invoke + 53
6   UIKitCore                           0x000000015bea39f3 __59-[_UITextInteractableItemCache _cachedItemInSet:predicate:]_block_invoke + 16
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a532658 __40-[NSSet objectsWithOptions:passingTest:]_block_invoke + 20
8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a431524 **NSSET_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a431800 __NSSetEnumerate + 730
10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011a532544 -[NSSet objectsWithOptions:passingTest:] + 207
11  UIKitCore                           0x000000015bea3990 -[_UITextInteractableItemCache _cachedItemInSet:predicate:] + 117
12  UIKitCore                           0x000000015bea2f87 -[_UITextInteractableItemCache itemForAttachment:range:] + 182
13  UIKitCore                           0x000000015b0531b5 +[_UITextInteractableItem itemForAttachment:range:textItemInteractingView:location:] + 117
14  UIKitCore                           0x000000015c342f62 -[UITextView _textInteractableItemAtPoint:precision:] + 1184
15  UIKitCore                           0x000000015c25982b -[_UITextSimpleLinkInteraction _canBeginInteractionSessionForLinkAtPoint:asTap:precision:] + 94
16  UIKitCore                           0x000000015c2595f9 -[_UITextSimpleLinkInteraction interaction_gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:] + 232
17  UIKitCore                           0x000000015c257bd0 -[UITextInteraction gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:] + 289
18  UIKitCore                           0x000000015b83567b -[UIGestureRecognizer _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:forEvent:] + 477
19  UIKitCore                           0x000000015b83501a -[UIGestureRecognizer

how to fix it? I need help

Comment: Well we'd need to see your code to help you. Also, when posting code, please don't just copy paste from your project, but submit a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.